# Filter output / print one record per event or time period

Tags: python, printf, filter, real-time, events

I've got a custom HID device which prints out exact coordinates of touched points at real time.

It is very sensitive & currently printing out the coordinate that's being touched on multiple numbers. But I need them to be printed one event at a time.

The crucial point is that I need the events to be printed without gap.(none of the events could be omitted to be printed) and of course no delay is allowed.

Current Form:

```
A1
A1
A1
A2
A2
C3
C3
C3
C3
C3
D1
D1
```

What I expect is:

```
A1
A2
C3
D1
```

Comment: Just use `uniq file.txt`?

Comment: Please check that Olorin's edit is correct. Of course it is better to show the output in code blocks, but the edit also changed the output from `A1 A1 A1 A2`... in one long line to `A1` `A1` `A1` `A2` ... in separate lines.

Comment: @Bodo if you inspect the [source of the original revision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/2f0ca807-6357-42f7-90d8-7ba0f51eecbf/view-source), it was one per line originally, but Markdown doesn't show it that way.

Comment: If `uniq` is working in a form of printing one from each type, then it won't work for my case. I need to just get the repetitive distinct touches as well. For example two different A1s can come one after. Or I need an exception handling mechanism in order not to send some wrong characters inside. So any ideas?